# How to show rotating spectrum gradient in PictureBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, gdi+

I basically want a rectangle in my form that shows a rainbow gradient and animates it(moving right), preferably as a background so I can show a transparent picture on top.

I tried animating a rainbow gif as the background, but the gif will never be as light as a code generated spectrum.

I also managed to implement a random code of a moving gradient, but this moves the gradient back and forth.

'''

```
Private Sub picCanvas_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e _
    As PaintEventArgs) Handles _
    WallpaperPreview.Paint
    ' Draw the background gradient.
    Dim br As New LinearGradientBrush(New Point(0, 0), New _
        Point(Me.ClientSize.Width, 0), Color.Red,
        Color.Blue)
    Dim color_blend As New ColorBlend
    color_blend.Colors = New Color() {Color.Red,
        Color.White, Color.Blue}
    color_blend.Positions = New Single() {0, m_Middle, 1}
    br.InterpolationColors = color_blend
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, Me.ClientRectangle)
    br.Dispose()

    ' Change the gradient's midpoint.
    m_Middle += m_Delta
    If (m_Middle > 1) OrElse (m_Middle < 0) Then m_Delta =
        -m_Delta
End Sub
```

'''

Is there a way I can convert this to an always right moving rainbow gradient?

Edit:
My solution is this

'''

```
Private posX As Single = 0
Private posXmover As Single = 10

Private Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
    WallpaperPreview.Invalidate()
End Sub

Private Sub WallpaperPreview_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e _
As PaintEventArgs) Handles _
WallpaperPreview.Paint
    Dim rect As New Rectangle(posX, 0,
        WallpaperPreview.ClientSize.Width * 2,
        WallpaperPreview.ClientSize.Height)
    Dim br As New LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.Red,
        Color.Blue, 0)
    Dim color_blend As New ColorBlend
    color_blend.Colors = New Color() {
            Color.Red,
            Color.Magenta,
            Color.Blue,
            Color.Cyan,
            Color.Green,
            Color.Yellow,
            Color.Red,
            Color.Magenta,
            Color.Blue,
            Color.Cyan,
            Color.Green,
            Color.Yellow,
            Color.Red}
    color_blend.Positions = New Single() {0, 0.083F, 0.163F, 0.249F, 0.332F, 0.415F, 0.5F, 0.583F, 0.66F, 0.749F, 0.832F, 0.915F, 1}
    br.InterpolationColors = color_blend
    e.Graphics.Clear(WallpaperPreview.BackColor)
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, Me.ClientRectangle)
    br.Dispose()
    posX += posXmover

End Sub
```

'''

Comment: You mean you want the color list to wrap around?

Comment: Is that the term? I don't know, I have a picture box in which I want to show a rainbow gradient that animates to the right. In android I used to do that by simply changing the values of the colors all together so that green would slowly turn yellow and so on, giving the impression that the gradient is moving to the right.

Comment: Using a `LinearGradientBrush` is the right way. What I would do is using a different target rectangle: Its width should be twince the control's width and the location should move either from 0 to -ctl.width or the other way. Also if you have only two colors make sure the brush has a WrapMode=TileFlipX; if you have more colors, i.e. a colorlist for a mulitcolor brush you should repeat the list and also make sure the last color is equal to the 1st one. In both cases only a clip of the full brush gradient is shown which move..

Comment: I understand exactly what you are saying and the logic behind it. Yes I do have a multicolor gradient set up, actually I have the exact gradient I want but I have no idea how to implement all this, I did extend the lineargradient to include all colors again, so now it starts with red, followed by the rest of the colors, then red again, then followed by all colors again and red again. But now i have no idea how to make the gradient move to a direction inside the picture box.

Comment: With some trial and error I managed to do it!